# What trait / concept can guarantee memsetting an object is well defined?

Tags: c++, c++14, metaprogramming, sfinae, c++20

Let's say I have defined a `zero_initialize()` function:

```
template<class T>
T zero_initialize()
{
    T result;
    std::memset(&result, 0, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}

// usage: auto data = zero_initialize<Data>();
```

Calling `zero_initialize()` for some types would lead to undefined behavior<sup>1,</sup> <sup>2</sup>. I'm currently enforcing `T` to verify [`std::is_pod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod). With that trait being deprecated in C++20 and the coming of concepts, I'm curious how `zero_initialize()` should evolve.

1. What (minimal) trait / concept can guarantee memsetting an object is well defined?
2. Should I use [`std::uninitialized_fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill) instead of `std::memset`? And why?
3. Is this function made obsolete by one of C++ initialization syntaxes for a subset of types? Or will it be with the upcoming of future C++ versions?

---

<sup>1)</sup> [Erase all members of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499078/5470596).
<sup>2)</sup> [What would be reason for “undefined behaviors” upon using memset on library class(std::string)? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30980240/5470596)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is std::is\_pod deprecated in C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225673/why-is-stdis-pod-deprecated-in-c20)

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Not a duplicate. `memset` is a different beast.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is technically no object property in C++ which specifies that user code can legally `memset` a C++ object. And that includes POD, so if you want to be technical, your code was never correct. Even TriviallyCopyable is a property about doing byte-wise copies between *existing* objects (sometimes through an intermediary byte buffer); it says nothing about inventing data and shoving it into the object's bits.

That being said, you can be *reasonably* sure this will work if you test `is_trivially_copyable` *and* `is_trivially_default_constructible`. That last one is important, because some TriviallyCopyable types still want to be able to control their contents. For example, such a type could have a private `int` variable that is always 5, initialized in its default constructor. So long as no code with access to the variable changes it, it will always be 5. The C++ object model guarantees this.

So you can't `memset` such an object and still get well-defined behavior from the object model.

Comment: I appreciate the double answer (language-lawyer/real life exists).

Answer (score 10):

> What (minimal) trait / concept can guarantee memsetting an object is well defined?

Per the [`std::memset` reference on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) the behavior of `memset` on a non *TriviallyCopyable* type is undefined.  So if it is okay to `memset` a *TriviallyCopyable* then you can add a `static_assert` to your class to check for that like

```
template<class T>
T zero_initialize()
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>, "Error: T must be TriviallyCopyable");
    T result;
    std::memset(&result, 0, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}
```

Here we use [`std::is_trivial_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) to make sure that not only is the class trivially copyable but it also has a trivial default constructor so we know it is safe to be zero initialized.

> Should I use `std::uninitialized_fill` instead of `std::memset`? And why?

You don't need to here since you are only initializing a single object.

> Is this function made obsolete by one of C++ initialization syntaxes for a subset of types? Or will it be with the upcoming of future C++ versions?

Value or braced initialization does make this function "obsolete".  `T()` and `T{}` will give you a value initialized `T` and if `T` doesn't have a default constructor it will be zero initialized.  That means you could rewrite the function as

```
template<class T>
T zero_initialize()
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>, "Error: T must be TriviallyCopyable");
    return {};
}
```

Comment: @RafałGórczewski OMG.  Can't believe I did that.  `memset` has the same requirements so I've just swapped the link and the function names.

Comment: It should be noted that TriviallyCopyable only guarantees that byte *copying* works. Setting the value of a type through a byte array is, as far as I'm aware, not allowed. Plus, TriviallyCopyable does *not* guarantee default-constructible. So your `zero_initialize` function isn't allowed. It would only work if you also verified `trivially_default_constructible`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Good point.  I've updated the code to use `std::is_trivial_v` to guarantee the class is completely trivial.

Comment: I cannot find those statements in standard as quoted in cppref.

Answer (score 0):

The most general definable trait that guarantees your `zero_initialize` will actually zero-initialize objects is

```
template <typename T>
struct can_zero_initialize :
    std::bool_constant<std::is_integral_v<
        std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_all_extents_t<T>>>> {};
```

Not too useful.  But the only guarantee about bitwise or bytewise representations of fundamental types in the Standard is [basic.fundamental]/7 "The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system."  There is no guarantee that a floating-point value with all bytes zero is a zero value.  There is no guarantee that any pointer or pointer-to-member value with all bytes zero is a null pointer value.  (Though both of these are usually true in practice.)

If all non-static members of a trivially-copyable class type are (arrays of) (cv-qualified) integral types, I think that would also be okay, but there's no possible way to test for that, unless reflection comes to C++.

Comment: This is true, but I think It does matter to me. Even if for some impl/arch a zero-representation doesn't imply a zero-semantic for some type, `zero_initialize()` is still well defined. It's up to the user not to assume things.