# Initializing structure object using std::fill

Tags: c++, std

I have below a structure and need to initialize the object of it using `std::fill`.

```
typedef struct _test
{
    char name[32];
    char key[4];
    int count;

}test;
```

As of now, I am using `memset`. I need to change it to `std::fill`. I have tried below but `std::fill` throws compiler error for the structure object.

```
test t;
char a[5];
std::fill(a, a + 5, 0);
std::fill(t, sizeof(t), 0);
```

Note: I don't want to initialize using this way. `char a[5] = {0};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need `std::fill` (or `std::memset`, on which you should read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53339370/817643)). Just value initialize the structure:

```
test t{};
```

This will in turn zero initialize all the fields. Beyond that, `std::fill` accepts a range, and `t, sizeof(t)` is not a range.

And as a final note, `typedef struct _test` is a needless C-ism. The structure tag in C++ is also a new type name. So what this does is pollute the enclosing namespace with a `_test` identifier. If you need C compatibility on the off-chance, the way to go is this

```
typedef struct test
{
    char name[32];
    char key[4];
    int count;

} test;
```

This sort of typedef is explicitly valid in C++, despite both the struct declaration and the `typedef` declaring the same type name. It also allows both C and C++ code to refer to the type as either `test` or `struct test`.

Comment: the structure was defined in one of the C library. My application is making using of that structure. I dont have control on the C library. I will be reusing the same object in different part of code and I need to reset the values to 0. In this case I have to use memset. So I asked this question to know, is there a way to replace memset with std::fill

Comment: @Arun - The fact you want to use memset or fill doesn't change the fact you don't need either for this in C++. You wanted zeros, I provided an answer the gives zeros with no effort.

Comment: And if you want to reset than `t = test{};` will do it just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried value initialization for an array. It is working same way as a structure. Is there any similar way for resetting arrays or I should go with std::fill or memset?

Comment: @Arun - Arrays would still require `std::fill`. Though if you use `std::array` it will have full value semantics too.